# NSUser Defaults vs. App Delegate for App Settings

Tags: iphone, core-data, settings, nsuserdefaults, appsettings

I currently have my app settings stored in an Entity called Settings. Each of my settings is an attribute. I have one Settings object which I load in my app delegate, and I access it through the delegate throughout the project. I am thinking of moving the settings to NSUser defaults. I would probably not need the Settings bundle since I have everything setup in the app. Besides the use of the settings bundle, I was wondering if anyone can tell me what are the benefits of using NSUserDefaults over my current method? Is there any way my choice can affect/improve app performance?

Comment: How does your settings object persist each setting?  Do you mean property instead of attribute?

Comment: I may not have the lingo down, sorry. I say attribute since I set each of the settings as an attribute on the entity in the Core Data Model, but I'm sure I do mean property. I access the settings object properties in this way: [[[UIApplication sharedDelegate] settings].showBudgets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are a substantial number of items to be saved then archiving or a plist such as you currently have may well be best.

One advantage of NSUserDefaults is that specific items can be accessed and saved from any method individually.  NSUserDefaults also supports several non object types.

Typically if I need to save essentially most of a classes state I will use archiving.

There is no reason not to use a combination, choose the method of persistence of each item individually.

Generally there will not be a large performance difference.

For substantial data choose Core Data.

Comment: Hi CocoaFu. Can you explain what you mean by archiving? Self taught programmer here..

Comment: Archiving is serializing a class instance to disk so that it can be read into memory later. Take a look at the `NSCoding` protocol and the various subjects on archiving in Apple's documentation. Basically, by implementing `NSCoding`, you specify how each piece of data in a class should be written to and read from disk. Then it's pretty easy to persist your data to a file.

Comment: Lucas Thanks! @JPK Most of us are self taught on iOS.  Read a lot.  Also consider sneaking into graduate courses, they don't take role and are generally held at night, I'l done that several times.

Comment: Thanks guys! I definitely have some more learning to do, though the curve is getting less steep. Seems like I should stick with my Settings object, accessed through the app delegate, for now, as there is not a huge advantage of using NSUserDefaults performance wise and what I have is working for me now. Eventually I would like to change it as I learn new and better (cleaner!) ways to code. Thanks for your input.